# Stripe API PHP Invalid Callback

Tags: php, curl

In summary: Stripe API: CurlClient.php has a CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION that cannot be found by curl on execution of the curl_exec command.

Stripe API version 3.2.0 (the newer version that uses namespace) using PHP version 5.4.45 and CURL version 7.36.0. I downloaded the library from GitHub and am using the init.php routine provided with the Library to bind the Stripe classes.

I can get a token using Stripe.js, pass to my server, authenticate and post a charge:

```
\Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => 400,
  "currency" => "cad",
  "source" => "tok_74MBD61UgMTtN7", // obtained with Stripe.js
  "description" => "Charge for test@example.com"
), array(
  "idempotency_key" => "yfwO6fUZh4qHctt6",
));
```

I get an error: Unexpected error communicating with Stripe.  If this problem persists, let us know at support@stripe.com.  (I have contacted Stripe and haven't heard from them in 3 days.)

My error routine shows: Invalid callback , no array or string given file (...)stripe-php-3.2.0/lib/HttpClient/CurlClient.php. Investigation shows the curl_exec in CurlClient.php throws the error because it can't find $headerCallback.  If I comment out this line:

```
$opts[CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION] = $headerCallback;
```

then everything works fine, except of course I don't get any headers passed back to the calling functions. However, I do get json returned and the successful charge can be seen from the Stripe Control Panel.

So, any ideas on why Strip API won't function properly?

Posting CurlClient.php here:

```
<?php

namespace Stripe\HttpClient;

use Stripe\Stripe;
use Stripe\Error;
use Stripe\Util;

class CurlClient implements ClientInterface
{
    private static $instance;

    public static function instance()
    {
        if (!self::$instance) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function request($method, $absUrl, $headers, $params, $hasFile)
    {
        $curl = curl_init();
        $method = strtolower($method);
        $opts = array();
        if ($method == 'get') {
            if ($hasFile) {
                throw new Error\Api(
                    "Issuing a GET request with a file parameter"
                );
            }
            $opts[CURLOPT_HTTPGET] = 1;
            if (count($params) > 0) {
                $encoded = self::encode($params);
                $absUrl = "$absUrl?$encoded";
            }
        } elseif ($method == 'post') {
            $opts[CURLOPT_POST] = 1;
            $opts[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $hasFile ? $params : self::encode($params);
        } elseif ($method == 'delete') {
            $opts[CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST] = 'DELETE';
            if (count($params) > 0) {
                $encoded = self::encode($params);
                $absUrl = "$absUrl?$encoded";
            }
        } else {
            throw new Error\Api("Unrecognized method $method");
        }

        // Create a callback to capture HTTP headers for the response
        $rheaders = array();
        $headerCallback = function ($curl, $header_line) use (&$rheaders) {
            // Ignore the HTTP request line (HTTP/1.1 200 OK)
            if (strpos($header_line, ":") === false) {
                return strlen($header_line);
            }
            list($key, $value) = explode(":", trim($header_line), 2);
            $rheaders[trim($key)] = trim($value);
            return strlen($header_line);
        };

        $absUrl = Util\Util::utf8($absUrl);
        $opts[CURLOPT_URL] = $absUrl;
        $opts[CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER] = true;
        $opts[CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT] = 30;
        $opts[CURLOPT_TIMEOUT] = 80;
        $opts[CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER] = true;
        $opts[CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION] = $headerCallback;
        $opts[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = $headers;
        if (!Stripe::$verifySslCerts) {
            $opts[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
        }

        curl_setopt_array($curl, $opts);
        $rbody = curl_exec($curl);

        if (!defined('CURLE_SSL_CACERT_BADFILE')) {
            define('CURLE_SSL_CACERT_BADFILE', 77);  // constant not defined in PHP
        }

        $errno = curl_errno($curl);
        if ($errno == CURLE_SSL_CACERT ||
            $errno == CURLE_SSL_PEER_CERTIFICATE ||
            $errno == CURLE_SSL_CACERT_BADFILE
        ) {
            array_push(
                $headers,
                'X-Stripe-Client-Info: {"ca":"using Stripe-supplied CA bundle"}'
            );
            $cert = self::caBundle();
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cert);
            $rbody = curl_exec($curl);
        }

        if ($rbody === false) {
            $errno = curl_errno($curl);
            $message = curl_error($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            $this->handleCurlError($absUrl, $errno, $message);
        }

        $rcode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($curl);
        return array($rbody, $rcode, $rheaders);
    }

    /**
     * @param number $errno
     * @param string $message
     * @throws Error\ApiConnection
     */
    private function handleCurlError($url, $errno, $message)
    {
        switch ($errno) {
            case CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT:
            case CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST:
            case CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEOUTED:
                $msg = "Could not connect to Stripe ($url).  Please check your "
                 . "internet connection and try again.  If this problem persists, "
                 . "you should check Stripe's service status at "
                 . "https://twitter.com/stripestatus, or";
                break;
            case CURLE_SSL_CACERT:
            case CURLE_SSL_PEER_CERTIFICATE:
                $msg = "Could not verify Stripe's SSL certificate.  Please make sure "
                 . "that your network is not intercepting certificates.  "
                 . "(Try going to $url in your browser.)  "
                 . "If this problem persists,";
                break;
            default:
                $msg = "Unexpected error communicating with Stripe.  "
                 . "If this problem persists,";
        }
        $msg .= " let us know at support@stripe.com.";

        $msg .= "\n\n(Network error [errno $errno]: $message)";
        throw new Error\ApiConnection($msg);
    }

    private static function caBundle()
    {
        return dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../data/ca-certificates.crt';
    }

    /**
     * @param array $arr An map of param keys to values.
     * @param string|null $prefix
     *
     * Only public for testability, should not be called outside of CurlClient
     *
     * @return string A querystring, essentially.
     */
    public static function encode($arr, $prefix = null)
    {
        if (!is_array($arr)) {
            return $arr;
        }

        $r = array();
        foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
            if (is_null($v)) {
                continue;
            }

            if ($prefix && $k && !is_int($k)) {
                $k = $prefix."[".$k."]";
            } elseif ($prefix) {
                $k = $prefix."[]";
            }

            if (is_array($v)) {
                $enc = self::encode($v, $k);
                if ($enc) {
                    $r[] = $enc;
                }
            } else {
                $r[] = urlencode($k)."=".urlencode($v);
            }
        }

        return implode("&", $r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try passing the amount as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be environmental. My PHP (5.4.45) was installed using CageFS and I used the 5.4 version that was NOT native, allowing for selection of various PHP modules. When I switched to native version of PHP 5.4 then stripe API started working just fine.  Also works well in PHP 5.5.  This may be of interest to other Cloud Linux users working with CageFS and PHP Selector.